# How to restore into Daedalus a wallet created with cardano-cli

Tags: wallet, cardano-cli, daedalus

I have created a wallet key pair using `cardano-cli address key-gen`.

Is there any way to restore this wallet on Yoroi or Daedalus visual interface?

Answer (score 2):

The only way those wallets allow for importing wallets is via the mnemonic key phrase.
As far as I remember `cardano-cli address key-gen` does generate the keys right away.
So no, there's no way to import the keys generated in cardano cli into Daedalus or Yoroi.